# Error on trying to use tensorboard with google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, google-colaboratory

I am getting an error on trying to use tensorboard with google collab.
I am using ngork to run tensorboard. The error is as follows

[image: Error Snapshot]

The code I am using to do the above-mentioned operation is as follows

```
LOG_DIR = '/content/drive/My Drive/Practice/Su'
get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)

!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux- 
amd64.zip
!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 6006 &')

! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0] 
['public_url'])"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip `ngrok` and use the built-in `%tensorboard` magic.

Here's a demo:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb

Comment: A working link https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

First uninstall tensorboard and tensorflow:

```
!pip3 uninstall tensorboard
!pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

then install tf-nightly:

```
!pip3 install --ignore-installed tf-nightly
```

then run tensorboard inside google colab:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}
```